# Java split doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to split date ( examp. 28.08 ) for 2 parts: 28 and 08 by "."

```
private String szukajDnia(String data){
      String[] dni = {"poniedziałek","wtorek","środa","czwartek","piątek","sobota","niedziela"};
      String dataZseparatorem = "";

      for(int i = 0; i < dni.length; i++){
            if(data.startsWith(dni[i]) == true){
                    dataZseparatorem = data.substring(dni[i].length());
            }
      }

      String dzien[] = dataZseparatorem.split("\\.");
      // dzien[0] - day
      // dzien[1] - month

      return dzien[0];
 }

private String szukajMiesiaca(String data){

          String[] dni = {"poniedziałek","wtorek","środa","czwartek","piątek","sobota","niedziela"};
            String dataZseparatorem = "";

           for(int i = 0; i < dni.length; i++){
            if(data.startsWith(dni[i]) == true){
                    dataZseparatorem = data.substring(dni[i].length());
                }
            }

            String dzien[] = dataZseparatorem.split("\\.");
            // dzien[0] - dzien
            // dzien[1] - miesiac

            return dzien[1];
        }
```

It work's good only when I get dzien[0], but when I try get dzien[1] ( month), i have error `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1`

input for example:
poniedzalek28.08
correctly output
08  or 28 when I want get a day

```
 public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler()
                    .handleResponse(response);
      try {

                // Get top-level JSON Object - a Map
                JSONObject responseObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(
                        JSONResponse).nextValue();

                JSONObject resultsObject = responseObject.getJSONObject("results");

                // / wchodzimy do arraya List
                JSONArray collectionArray = resultsObject.getJSONArray("collection1");

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + plan);
                writer = new PrintWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + plan);


                for (int i = 0; i < collectionArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject listObject = (JSONObject) collectionArray.get(i);

                    String DzienData = listObject.getString("property1");
                    String Godzina= listObject.getString("property2");
                    String Rodzaj = listObject.getString("property5");
                    String Program = listObject.getString("property7");
                    String Uwagi = listObject.getString("property8");

                    result.add(""+DzienData+"\n"+Godzina+"\n"+Rodzaj+"\n"+Program+"\n"+Uwagi);

                    listaDni.add(szukajDnia(DzienData)); // it work's ( dzien[0])
                    listaMiesiecy.add(szukajMiesiaca(DzienData)); // it isn't work's (dzien[1])
                    lokacja.add(Uwagi);
                    opis.add(Program);

                }
                writer.close();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think the Pattern.quote() portion is necessary, what happens if you just do `.split(".")`?  Also, where are you trying to access `dzien[1]`? You are only returning `dzien[0]`, and `String dzien[]` is allocated inside your private method, so you can't access it anywhere else.  Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: read the documentation for `Pattern.quote`. why do you use this method?

Comment: Ok, I fix this, but it still isn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this code and it works as expected:

```
 String data = "poniedziałek28.08";
 String[] dni = {"poniedziałek","wtorek","środa","czwartek","piątek","sobota","niedziela"};
 String dataZseparatorem = "";

for(int i = 0; i < dni.length; i++){
 if(data.startsWith(dni[i]) == true){
         dataZseparatorem = data.substring(dni[i].length());
     }
 }
System.out.println(dataZseparatorem);
 String dzien[] = dataZseparatorem.split(Pattern.quote("."));

 System.out.println(dzien[0] + " " + dzien[1]);
```

Please check your input and see if is in UTF-8 (with all the accentuated characters).

Comment: Input unfortunately is ok :(

Comment: But it's still working, are you sure? If the input you receives doesn't match any of the word in your array, you'll get that ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Did you try the code in a separate program to see if everything else is fine? Because the code I posted outputs both the numbers as expected, which means the problem must be elsewhere. Can you isolate it to a bare minimum test case and debug in an IDE to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the string using `.` you must use `\\.`

```
String dzien[] = dataZseparatorem.split("\\.");
```

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying it's a must. The API doc for Pattern.quote says that 
" This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern" - so, OP's question is actually valid.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same as @prabugp but he was faster. Yes, your code works as designed.

Nevertheless let me give a hint for **good coding practice**:

When you declare an array you can use the syntax `String dzien[]` instead of `String[] dzien` but it is discouraged by Oracle themselves and they give the explanation also, see the following passage quoted from this site: [Oracle Tutorial - Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> You can also place the brackets after the array's name:
>
> // this form is discouraged 
>   float anArrayOfFloats[];
>
> However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the
>   array type and should appear with the type designation.

Of course this alone doesn't help with your problem, but if show us the concrete data used maybe we can help further.

**Edit - added**

For example, we don't know what this object is and what the method really does:

```
listaMiesiecy.add(...)
```

It seems to be a List type like ArrayList but your information doesn't stress this explicitly. So maybe that's a self-written class and the error occurs in its method `add()`?